# VSCode Python debugging doesn't have same PATH as interpreter

Tags: python, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code

Essentially, using the debugger doesn't seem to be loading my .zshrc while the integrated terminal does. i.e. this simple test outputs different code when I debug vs. when I just call pytest in the terminal:

```py
class TestPath(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_path(self):
        import os
        print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

This is a problem for me as I use `shutil.which(...)` to find executables. I know it's finding the correct Python since `sys.version` yields the same results in both the debugger REPL and through terminal.

I even added the following block to my settings.json which I never had before to explicitly point to the correct shell:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
      "zsh (login)": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/zsh",
        "args": ["-l"]
      }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": "/usr/bin/zsh",
```

This has never been problem till recently, and I've had lots of debugging related issues since VSCode 1.62. I've downgraded twice and even set `"update.mode" : "none"`, but Bill seemingly keeps hacking in and forcing me to upgrade.

Any insight is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to update the `Python Extension`? some people have run across a similar problem, you can have a look at this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17678).